# Css custom cursors behave strangely while the page is loading

Tags: javascript, css

I use the css-crusor property with an url-value.

In chrome the cursor behaves very strangely while the page is loading. Once I :hoover the element, the custom cursor flickers, and the returns to normal.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this?

Here is the site:
http://dev.nuagency.se/illustrators/beata-boucht-2/
after launch, It will be:
[http://nuagency.se/illustrators/beata-boucht-2/](http://dev.nuagency.se/illustrators/beata-boucht-2/)

I run chrome 19.0.1084.56

Comment: Please show your related javascript css and html or provide a demo.  This could be cause by elements overlapping, floats, errorneous javascript etc. without some code it will be a wild goose chase.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing this in Chrome. Is the cursor the big blue arrow when hovering over the largest image? Your question feels as if it's taking a long time to load for you (it's very quick for me, so difficult to check). Have you considered playing with the size to see if that makes a difference? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623769/css-custom-cursor-doesnt-work-in-ff-chrome)

Comment: @ZhihaoJia: I use samller cursor now, the problem persists. While loading, running the cursor on and then off the image generates the error. The custom cursor flickers and then returns the standard image. If you just put the cursor on top of the image while the page is loading, it will remain being the standard-cursor until you remove it from the image and then put's it back again.