# how to set a specific cursor in html

Tags: html, cursor

I wanted to know why this custom cursor doesn't work:

```
html{
cursor: url("../../../../../../Oxygen_Cursors%5B2%5D.fw.png");
}
```

Comment: I don't see any relevance between your Questions title and body

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: I'd rename the file avoiding special characters like `%5B2%5D`. And double check your path. You might easily end up in the wrong directory.

Comment: Sorry about that @apomene I was going to ask another question and didn't know that the title had saved, fixed it know

Comment: @Falko I have removed all of the special characters and shouldn't the directory already work since I used the search for url tool to find it?

Comment: @SableFoste I mean that it doesn't show the cursor I have set when I open the webpage

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell the reason for your problem. But you might want to check the following:

- Is the path correct? (I don't know what "search for url tool" you are referring to.)
- Are special characters an issue? (Ok, you already checked that.)
- Does your browser support PNG cursor images? IE, for example, does not.
- Does your browser support the image size?
- Does your browser require another non-url option, like "auto"? Firefox, for example, does.

For more details, have a look into [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6623769/3419103) and [this reference](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/cursor.html).

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite broad, but you could try using the following code

```
<BODY style="CURSOR: url('cursor file name.ani')">
```

replace the "cursor file name.ani" part with the name of your cursor file.