# How to fix a custom cursor that doesn't show on hover

Tags: html, css

I have set an image as a custom cursor for when you hover over a certain element. However, it's not showing and I can't figure out why.

```css
span#me:hover {
    cursor: url("links/_moi.jpg"), auto;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
 <h2>My name is <span id="me">Natalie Taylor</span> and I am a graphic designer based in Frankfurt am Main, Germany.</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that `span.me` means a span with *class* `me` while you have a span with *id* `me`.

**EDIT:** In addition to this you need to have your image resized to under ***32x32*** pixels. Anything above that will be ignored.

Comment: I've updated it now but the image still isn't showing. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think the issue is the icon size. You need it to be less than 32x32 to work. 
This is actually a Windows restriction as stated in this thread: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623948/2629954)

Edited original answer.

Comment: oH that's probably it then that would make a lot of sense. My image is quite a bit bigger haha. I guess I'll just have to do it with JS

Answer (score 2):

`#` is used to target the element with a specific ID

`.` (dots) are used to target the element with a specific Class

Try

```
span#me:hover {
    cursor: url("links/_moi.jpg");
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: ahh I changed it from a class to an id and forgot to update the css. I've updated it now but the image still isn't showing. Any other ideas?

Comment: no, the correct image is showing up in brackets when I hover over it

Comment: I've not seen ', auto' used before, try removing that? - Answer edited

Comment: @Natalie, I'm not sure but some browsers might not support jpg cursors or have a maximum resolution. Have you tried it with a `.cur` file?

Comment: i changed the file to .cur but it hasn't changed anything the mouse is still the text cursor when I hover it over :(

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting span infront of ID, since ID is unique and can be used only once.

```css
    #me:hover {
        cursor: url("links/_moi.jpg") auto;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

Or try changing from ID to class and call it into your span.

```css
    span .me:hover {
        cursor: url("links/_moi.jpg") auto;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

```html
 <h2>My name is <span class="me">Natalie Taylor</span> and I am a graphic designer based in Frankfurt am Main, Germany.</h2>
```

**EDIT:**

While changing it to pointer without an image it works, try checking if a path to image is correct and if image file is correct (.jpg, .png, ...)

```css
.me:hover {
    cursor: url("links/_moi.jpg"), auto;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<h2>My name is <span class="me">Natalie Taylor</span> and I am a graphic designer based in Frankfurt am Main, Germany.</h2>
```

Comment: Removing the span from it doesn't help :(. I had it as a class before and it wasn't working which is why I tried changing it to id

Comment: I've edited my answer, maybe those colons were the problem. And try making .me class without :hover pseudo-class.

Comment: My best guess is that your image is causing problems, check if image is smaller or equal than 32x32.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's something wrong with the image you use or the location of the image. This one works with your code.

```css
span#me:hover {
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/happy.png"), auto;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<h2>My name is <span id="me">Natalie Taylor</span> and I am a graphic designer based in Frankfurt am Main, Germany.</h2>
```