# Internal CSS Cursor URL Not Working, any tips?

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am trying to add a custom cursor using cursor: url and it is not working. I have tried different links and different browsers (I am currently in Chrome) and it is still not working. Could somebody help me, I am new to coding and CSS.

```html
 <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58485538b772315a9e4dd5d9.png" />
  <title>
     Ella's (kinda) First Webpage
  </title>    
   <style>
  
    body {
       cursor: url('https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/58485538b772315a9e4dd5d9.png'), auto;
       } 
</style>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS custom cursor doesn't work in FF/Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623769/css-custom-cursor-doesnt-work-in-ff-chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are limitations to what kind of images you can use as a custom cursor. As a reference check this **[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Basic_User_Interface/Using_URL_values_for_the_cursor_property?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fcursor%2Furl)**.
I would say your image is too big (maximum 32x32px).

Try the following code with a url to a placeholder image with 32px.

```
body {
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
   cursor:url(https://via.placeholder.com/32), auto;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use .png, .cur or .gif for cursors, and don't have bigger than 32px images due to some browsers don't support higher.

Example below:

```css
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  cursor: url('https://reygif.com/media/emoticon-hello-kitty-18039.gif'), auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  Ella's (kinda) First Webpage
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

File's dimensions of `58485538b772315a9e4dd5d9.png` are too big, resize it.

I've download the file and i've resize it with Photoshop (`43px` × `34px`) and it works!